# Trouble with regexp in PHP

Tags: php, html, regex

Funny that my last question was on the same topic, but alas:

I'm running the following code:

```
preg_match('/<th.*>.*Organizer.*title=\".*\">(.*)<\/a>/mi', $file_string, $organizer);
```

On the following content:

```
<tr>
<th valign="top"> Organizer:
</th>
<td style="width:55%;"> <a href="/starcraft2/TaKe" title="TaKe">TaKe</a>
</td></tr>
```

And I can't for the life of me figure out why it's not working. I can get it to match  Organizer: with the regexp '/.*Organizer', but it seems that as soon as there's a new line it stops to work, despite having the /m option. Any ideas?

Comment: Its a multiline output? because your regex I believe doesn't say it should traverse lines, so by default it works on one line

Comment: My bad, php's `m` behavior is multiline

Comment: Your problem is that `.*` does NOT match newline

Comment: Isn't `/s` the modifier you are looking for? http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php

Comment: If you use the /m option this first piece of code `<th.*>` will match everything till the last `>` that's your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so the issue is the new-line constant, however this Regex will get the text of the `a` element:

```
<th.*|\n>.*|\nOrganizer.*|\n*title=".*">(.*)<\/a>
```

Take note to the expression `*|\n`.

Here is a [Regex 101](http://regex101.com/r/kX4sS0) to prove it.

---

As `Niet` stated, you could just use the `s` modifier. The Regex would then be:

```
<th.*>.*Organizer.*title=".*">(.*)<\/a>
```

but you would send in an additional modifier - `s`. Here is a [Regex 101](http://regex101.com/r/jV7pS6) to prove it.

Comment: Why not just use the DOTALL modifier `s`?

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol, fantastic idea--thanks a lot! You learn something new every day!

Comment: [I too would use](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21138662/) the `s` modifier instead. That's a lot more easier.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help, however, I've run into an interesting problem. I'm trying to grab this data from [this page](http://wiki.teamliquid.net/starcraft2/ASUS_ROG_NorthCon_2013) from the table on the right hand side, and the regexp you provided is working fine when taking out the text on its own, but as soon as I try to get the page with file_get_contents() and run the regexp on that, the match stops working. Any ideas? Perhaps this is a question in itself.

Answer (score 0):

The dot metacharacter, by default, does not match newlines. If you also want `.` to match newlines, you need the `s` modifier.

From the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php):

> If this modifier is set, a dot metacharacter in the pattern matches all characters, **including newlines**. Without it, newlines are excluded.

However, it's generally a bad idea to use regex to parse HTML. I suggest you use a [DOM Parser](http://php.net/dom) instead.